# html5 fullscreen API for mobile device

Tags: html, mobile, fullscreen

Can it?

I've tried and it run OK on PC but none of my mobile device success (ipad, nexus 7, samsung galaxy S3, Kindle fire HD...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Browser support for the Full screen API is actually very poor according to http://caniuse.com/#search=fullscreen

If you really need to use the whole screen for your application, you should find an alternative for mobile users.

This Javascript hack may help you: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/mobile-web-apps/remove-address-bar/